# pandas iterate thru column row

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to iterate thru a pandas dataframe column from reading a CSV file...

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('vavs.csv', dtype={'trunkAdress':str}, index_col='mechTag')


for column in df[['areaServed']]:
    # Select column contents by column name using [] operator
    columnSeriesObj = df[column]
    print('Colunm Name : ', column)
    print('Column Contents : ', columnSeriesObj.values)
```

This will print:

```
Colunm Name :  areaServed
Column Contents :  ['103_104' '101_105' '102' '110' '11' '114_116' '115_121' '117' '118_120']
```

But why will this not print `hit`? I dont understand why the statement is not True. What would I need to change in order to print`hit`?

```
if columnSeriesObj.values.any() == '11':
    print('hit!')
```

Comment: check out the .any() docs https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html. `columnSeriesObj.values.any()` will return a bool, which will never equal a string.

Comment: if i remove the `.any()` I get a `The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()` any idea to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are supposed to check `any` on bool series as follows:

```
for column in df[['areaServed']]:
    # Select column contents by column name using [] operator
    columnSeriesObj = df[column]
    print('Colunm Name : ', column)
    print('Column Contents : ', columnSeriesObj.values)
    if (columnSeriesObj.values == '11').any():
        print('hit!')
```

Output:

```
Colunm Name :  areaServed
Column Contents :  ['103_104' '101_105' '102' '110' '11' '114_116' '115_121' '11
7' '118_120']
hit!
```

Answer (score 0):

`columnSeriesObj.values.any()` returns whether any element is True. In your case `columnSeriesObj.values.any()` will evaluate to True which will not equal `'11'' so nothing will print.

You could try something like this:

```
val = [ii for ii in columnSeriesObj.values if ii == '11']
if val:
    print('hit')
```

or something like this with numpy:

```
if np.any(columnSeriesObj.values == value):
    print('hit')
```